# Sapper routes with arbitrary number of nesting levels

Tags: routes, nuxt.js, svelte

After doing some comparative tests between Nuxt and Sapper, I'm considering using Sapper in production for a new project, but there's one issue that I need to solve. The site has a hierarchical page structure, with categories and sub categories up to 4 levels deep. However, the depth varies. So this gives me routes like so:

```
[category]/[subcat_1]/[subcat_2]/[...]/[page].html
```

How do I prevent having to duplicate my page templates for each possible level? In Nuxt I would use a router instead of the `pages` dir, but in Sapper this is not (yet) possible?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you're right, this isn't *yet* possible. It's a high priority though — something we intend to tackle in June.

Comment: Thanks. Would be great if you could manage to do this in June, it would be _just_ in time for my project!

Comment: I don't know what the status of this is, but I've gone ahead and implemented a router myself. Right now it's a plugin for my particular app, but I guess with a couple of hours I could turn it into a package that can be used in any sapper app. Let me know if you're interested.

Comment: I’m interested. ;-) Any chance you can link to a gist or something?

Comment: Is this now possible? Using the [] for directory names with _layout.svelte, it seems I'm able to achieve a set number of nested levels.

Just wondering if there's a way to have deep nested levels without creating the same number of subdirectories?